# Extracting data from one worksheet to another in excel

Tags: vba, excel

Lets say we have these columns

```
Sarah    Smith     1234566 UK
Homer    Simpson   3456677 USA
Max      Power     4567932 Canada
Meg      Griffin   5689321 USA
Sarah    Smith   345677   USA
```

So I wanna exctract all data for one person be in a  worksheet, so Sarah Smith has her own worksheet that shows her info, homer simpson has his own that shows his info..
**I wrote this code, but when i run it starts each work but it adds a row on top of each worksheet!!! so for sarah smith work sheet it starts from row 2, for Homer Simpson starts from row 3. Max power starts from row 4?? Any idea why?? I want each sheet starts from row 1**

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    Dim WorksheetsExists As Boolean, e
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    With Range("A1").CurrentRegion
        With .Offset(1).Columns(1)
            For Each e In Filter(.Parent.Evaluate("transpose(if(countif(offset(" & _
                                                  .Address & ",0,0,row(1:" &     .Rows.Count & "))," & .Address & ")=1," & _
                                                  .Address & ",char(2)))"), Chr(2), False)
                .Offset(-1).AutoFilter 1, e
                Range("A1").CurrentRegion.Offset(0, 0).Resize(.Rows.Count, 25).SpecialCells(12).Copy
                On Error Resume Next
                WorksheetExists = (Sheets(e).Name <> "")
                If WorksheetExists = False Then
                    Sheets.Add(After:=Sheets(Sheets.Count)).Name = e
                    Sheets(e).Range("A" & Sheets(e).Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row).Offset(1).PasteSpecial
                    On Error GoTo 0
                Else
                    Sheets(e).Range("A" & Sheets(e).Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row).Offset(1).PasteSpecial
                End If
                Sheets(e).Columns.AutoFit
            Next
        End With
        .AutoFilter
    End With
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
End Sub
```

Comment: Can you try `Sheets(e).Rows.Count` in your `.PasteSpecial` method?

Comment: It created the sheets but all blank

Comment: I do not think you need such a complicated expression.. `Sheets(e).Range("A1").PasteSpecial` should work. Yes, the previous makes sense to be blank: the new sheet is empty, and the expression returns an error..

Answer (score 1):

I tested this, with small modifications:

```
Sub sof20317616ExtractingDataFrom1Worksheet2Another()
  Dim lRow As Long
  Dim WorksheetExists As Boolean, e

  Application.ScreenUpdating = False
  With Range("A1").CurrentRegion
    'MsgBox .Offset(1).Columns(1).Rows.Count
    With .Offset(1).Columns(1)
      For Each e In Filter(.Parent.Evaluate("transpose(if(countif(offset(" & _
        .Address & ",0,0,row(1:" & .Rows.Count & "))," & .Address & ")=1," & _
        .Address & ",char(2)))"), Chr(2), False)
        .Offset(-1).AutoFilter 1, e
        'MsgBox .Rows.Count
        'Range("A1").CurrentRegion.Offset(0, 0).Resize(.Rows.Count, 25).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy
        .Offset(0, 0).Resize(.Rows.Count, 25).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy
        On Error Resume Next
        WorksheetExists = (Sheets(e).Name <> "")
        If WorksheetExists = False Then
          Sheets.Add(After:=Sheets(Sheets.Count)).Name = e
          On Error GoTo 0
        End If
        lRow = Sheets(e).Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
        Sheets(e).Range("A" & lRow).Offset(0).PasteSpecial
        Sheets(e).Columns.AutoFit
      Next
    End With
    .AutoFilter
  End With

  Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

With the initial datasheet as this:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This isn't an answer to your question per se, but I think there's a flaw in your Boolean test for `WorkSheetExists`. Note that once it's set to True, i.e., the first time a worksheet whose name is the value of e, exists, it won't become False again. That's because the `On Error Resume` next statement skips over the error when the a worksheet of that name doesn't exist. It does not set your WorkSheetExists variable back to False. You need to do that explicitly in your code like:

```
On Error Resume Next
WorksheetExists = False
WorksheetExists = (Sheets(e).Name <> "")
If WorksheetExists = False Then ...
```

Better yet, create a separate WorkSheetExists function that you just pass the name to:

```
Function WorkSheetExists (WorkbookToTest as Workbook, WorksheetName as String) as Boolean
    On Error Resume Next
    WorksheetExists = WorkbookToTest.Sheets(WorksheetName).Name <> ""
End Function
```